# Not able to retrieve lead ads from Facebook webhooks

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

I have subscribed for leadgen on facebook devlopers- webhooks. I can't receive any real-time leads. And my app is in development mode. If I switch the mode, all the permissions set for the app are gone.

Comment: _“If I switch the mode, all the permissions set for the app are gone.”_ - well yeah, you need to get your app reviewed first.

Comment: App review Is done! But, business verification is in review. How many days does it take to complete? Do you have any idea?